# UnityRemote4 doesn't work with Samsung SIII?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying execute UnityRemote4 to debug my game on Android.

I have an Samsung SIII GT-I9300, I did install Java/SDK/UnityRemote4 and set my SIII to Developer Options and checked Debug USB.

On Unity I selected SDK on Preferences>External Tools>SDK Location In Edit>Project Settings>Editor>Device I set Any Android Device

When I execute Play on Unity doesn't display game in UnityRemote4 and message: "Connect this device with a USB cable to your computer. Press PLAY in the Unity Editor to test" stay

When I execute Build&Run, the apk is installed but I can't debug Touch

How can I do this works ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I changed connection USB to PTP and now works.